# How to read file from host, write inside docker container

Tags: docker

I am using a container to build my C++ project. The project is in fact composed of multiple projects inside different directories, all at the same level. For example, I might want to build projects in directories A and B that are sub-directories of directory R. To do this, I mount directory R inside the container. However, when I build the project inside the container the build artifacts are written back to the host because of the bind, this pollutes my host. I cannot create the bind as readonly because the build inside the container will fail since the container cannot write inside the directory.

A possible solution would be to copy the entire source code to the container at container build time but this would slow down my development process as I would need to rebuild the container every time I change the source code.

Another possible solution would be to generate the artifacts in another directory but this is not easily achievable in the current project I'm working on.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do here: read files from the host but keep container-generated files from polluting the host, everything in the same directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try copying the source files to a directory inside the container and then every time you run a build, use `rsync` between host directory and container directory to copy only the changed files.

This is essentially your copy solution which avoids copying all files every time.

If your container is running all the time you can run `rsync` in background mode so it syncs files as soon as they change. You can even trigger build automatically when it detects changes.

Comment: That's actually pretty smart, I didn't think about looking at the container like a host with its own IP address. Thank you!